# How do you replace a mask with a specific color?

Tags: c#, imagemagick.net

I am using the following code snippet to remove the background from an image.

```
int[] bgColors = {203,255,240}
ImageMagick.MagickImage image = new ImageMagick.MagickImage("input.jpg")
ImageMagick.MagickImage combineMask= new ImageMagick.MagickImage("mask.jpg")

combineMask.Blur(7, 30);

image.Composite(combineMask, ImageMagick.CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
image.Settings.BackgroundColor = new ImageMagick.MagickColor(bgColors[0], bgColors[1], bgColors[2]);
image.Alpha(ImageMagick.AlphaOption.Remove);
```

It takes the MagickImage `image` and the MagickImage `combineMask` and outputs a combined `image` as linked below.

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHThG.png) + [Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drSA2.png) = [Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl7d1.png)

Previously, I never needed anything other than a plain white background (which this provides). Now, I would like to be able to set the color of the background. I started by passing a non `(255,255,255)` set of colors to the settings to `image.Settings.BackgroundColor`. This did not accomplish anything. I've been trying to investigate the MagickImage library (through their github, they don't really have very complete documentation), but it has remained inscrutable.

How could I get `image.Alpha(ImageMagick.AlphaOption.Remove);` to replace the removed section with the background color (or a passed color), or otherwise change the color of the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I've figured out a Solution that takes me 90% of the way there.

```
int[] bgColors = {203,255,240}
ImageMagick.MagickImage image = new ImageMagick.MagickImage("input.jpg")
ImageMagick.MagickImage combineMask= new ImageMagick.MagickImage("mask.jpg")

combineMask.ColorFuzz = new ImageMagick.Percentage(5);

combineMask.Transparent(ImageMagick.MagickColor.FromRgb(255, 255, 255));
combineMask.Opaque(ImageMagick.MagickColor.FromRgb((byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0), 
ImageMagick.MagickColor.FromRgb((byte)bgColors[0], (byte)bgColors[1], (byte)bgColors[2]));

image.Composite(combineMask, ImageMagick.CompositeOperator.Over);
```

Instead of using the Black/White mask and grabbing alpha channels, I am converting the white part of the mask to transparent, then converting the black part of the mask to the colors contained in the bgColors.

Now, because the formerly white area is now transparent, I cannot blur the image in order to create a smooth transition between mask and picture, which I still need to fix.